# Batch file search & create with more than one word

Tags: search, batch-file, directory

I need your help, I am fairly new at this type of scripting, and I need your help to try and get this script to function correct.

I have a script that searches a folder for files and moves them to a folder name after the files first characters. But I have an issue when the files are seperated by more than one '.'.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
set "IncomingFolder=D:\Test"   
set "showsFolder=D:\Test\"

for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*.S*.*") do (   for /f "delims=.S" %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
if not exist "%showsFolder\%" md "%showsFolder%\%%A"
move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\%%A"   ) )
```

For example:
If the files is Hustle.SXX.XXX Then it makes the correct folder named "Hustle".
But if it is named The.Hustle.SXXX.XXX then it makes a folder called "The" only, I need it to use the whole name until ".S".

Anybody who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Test this to see how it goes:

```
@echo off
set "IncomingFolder=D:\Test"   
set "showsFolder=D:\Test"

for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*.S*.*") do (
   for /f "delims=" %%A in (' echo "%%~nF"^|repl ".(.*)S\d\d.*" "$1" ') do (
      md "%showsFolder%\%%A" 2>nul
      move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\%%A"
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed, but I had hoped to write it all in one file instead of calling another. But for the time being it is great for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "IncomingFolder=c:\sourcedir"   
set "showsFolder=D:\Test"

for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*.S*.*") do (for /f "delims=." %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
 ECHO md "%showsFolder%\%%A"
 ECHO move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\%%A\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I've changed the directory names to suit my system.

I could not recreate the problem you describe, but `delims=.S` would make the delimiters `.` **or** `S`, not `.S`. That may be what you are seeing.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

Also, the required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. From what I can tell, A file named `The.Hustle.SXXX.XXX` will still result in a folder named `The`, but the OP wants `The.Hustle`.

Comment: That is correct dbenham. I need it to seperate at ".S" So it always will make a folder based on any string it finds before that point that always is .S.

Comment: @dbenham Hmm - very probably. Specks on my specs. Need to clean the monitor. Can't rush these big jobs...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use FOR /F to parse from the front because you don't know how many `.` may appear in the name. I'm assuming you are expecting names like `part1.part2.Spart3.part4`, but not like `part1.part2.Spart3.part4.part5`. In other words - you don't want two dots after the `.S`. If so, then you can safely remove everything after the second to last dot. That is easily done using the `~n` modifier twice.

```
for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*.S*.*") do for %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
  if not exist "%showsFolder%\%%~nA" md "%showsFolder%\%%~nA"
  move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\%%~nA\"
)
```

(Tickled by Magoo - `%` missing on "incoming" and `~n` required on move-destination)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure how I can use this it the case I described, or actually I am not sure of how to correctly input in my scripts when I do, I get an error.

Comment: @Magoo - yes, thanks for the edits. Silly mistakes on my part.

Comment: @Lasser - ??? I do not understand your confusion. The code simply replaces the FOR loops in your code. And it should work with names like "The.Hustle.Sxx.xxx" and "Hustle.Sxx.xxx". It will not work properly on "This.Fails.Sxx.xxx.xxx".

Comment: @Lasser - never mind, I see you probably wrote the comment before Magoo fixed the code :-) It should wok now

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
set "IncomingFolder=D:\Test"   
set "showsFolder=D:\Test"

for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*.S*.*") do (
   set "file=%%~nF"
   for /F "delims=" %%A in ("!file:*.S=!") do set "folder=!file:.S%%~A=!"
   if not exist "%showsFolder%\!folder!" md "%showsFolder%\!folder!"
   move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\!folder!"
)
```

- `set "file=%%~nF"` get the file name, for example: `set "file=The.Hustle.SXXX.XXX"`
- `!file:*.S=!` is the part after the first ".S", for example `XXX.XXX`, so
- `set "folder=!file:.S%%~A=!"` is file name without ".SXXX.XXX", for example: "The.Hustle"